# How to prompt user for input and use input else where in batch file

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing

I am very new to batch scripting.  I am trying to prompt a user to "Enter directory path containing files to be converted:".  Once they enter that I want to prompt them to "Enter directory path to save files to once converted:".  My code currently prompts the first question, but then closes before the user can input anything.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set /p "SourcePath=Enter directory path containing files to be converted: "
echo %SourcePath%
set /p "TargetPath=Enter directory path to save files to once converted: "
echo %TargetPath%
pause
```